# How to get Customer Login and Logout outside Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, login, header, logout, customer-session

Hereby, I working to integrating **Header/Footer** section outside Magento using this sample code:

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
echo $mageFilename;
require_once $mageFilename;
#Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

//load default xml layout handle and generate blocks
$layout->getUpdate()->load('default');
$layout->generateXml()->generateBlocks();

//get the loaded head and header blocks and output
$headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
$headerBlock = $layout->getBlock('header');
echo $headBlock->toHtml() . $headerBlock->toHtml();..


reset of your code
```

When i get all header/footer content include site Logo and etc.But it doesn't get **Login and Logout** from that Header section. Here i Sample Headers

[image: DEMO Outside Magento] 
 and  sample Header for Magento Website 
[image: DEMO Magento]
How to call Login And logout detail outside magento.Kindly advise me any other issues?

Comment: You say you are building your site 'outside' of Magento? Is the site in some other CMS that you want to interact with Magento?

Comment: Yes @JasonTipton..I am interact with core php file with magento.How to achieve outside magento with same header and footer..I get header without login links.How to get Header without login details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Links to add Login and Logout links are in the `<customer_logged_in>` and `<customer_logged_out>` handles, respectively.

Add them to your script with the following code:

```
if( Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_in');
} else {
    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_out');
}
```

Comment: i executed your code into my custom page.No response any other change can taken in magento?Kindly advise me..How to achieve login and logout outside magento?

Comment: Use `$this->getLayout()->getNode()->asNiceXml()` to see what layout instructions are currently being loaded.  See if the the appropriate handles and blocks are in the layout.

Answer (score 3):

First check if user logged in or not then add log in/log out to your header :
 use the following code:

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
   $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_in');
}else{
   $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_logged_out');
}
```

Comment: please put some details thus anyone can understand  the code